# How to use useRef to change the style of a element?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, inline-styles

I want to use the `useRef` hook to change the style of a DOM element:

```
const Box = props => {
  const box = useRef(0);

  const onClick = () => {
    box.current.backgroundColor = "blue";
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        ref={box}
        style={{ width: "300px", height: "300px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
      />
      <button onClick={onClick}>Change color of box</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

However, if I click on the button the `backgroundColor` of the `box` doesn't change.

I also created a [simple code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/embed/billowing-shadow-tt98l), which illustrates my problem.

Comment: try this box.current.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're trying to modify a non-existent `backgroundColor` property directly on your DOM element:

```
box.current.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Which would (if it worked) modify your DOM element to this:

```
<div backgroundColor="blue" ... />
```

In order to make it work you need to modify the `backgroundColor` through the `style` property:

```
box.current.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

[Working version of your snippet](https://codesandbox.io/embed/sleepy-cannon-64qry)

Comment: don't forgot for sizable styles use "px" or percent

Comment: I had the correct implementation for my usecase but forgot the 'px', thanks Hamidreza Sadegh!